# Is this sentence correct "Now that I am looking at it closely, I can see it's not that special."

Tags: sentence-structure

Is this sentence correct? 
I'm confused about the use of 'that'in the sentence.
Can you please guide me?

Comment: It looks correct to me.  What is confusing you about "that"?

Comment: Look at definition 11 [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/that): "to a great extent or degree; very."  Does that help?

Comment: **That** is often used to mean **so** or **very**. **Not that special** = **Not so special**. **He wasn't that helpful** means **he wasn't very helpful**.